# Problems uploading files using selenium +pthon

Tags: python, selenium

I tried to upload a video, but unfortunately failed, but I don't know where my code is wrong

html:

```
<button aria-label="浏览" class="button button--secondary" type="button"><span class="button__content"><span dir="auto" class="button__label">浏览</span></span></button>
<span class="button__content"><span dir="auto" class="button__label">浏览</span></span>
<span dir="auto" class="button__label">浏览</span>
```

my python:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="main-content"]/div/section[1]/div/div[2]/fieldset-section[2]/input-submit/button')).send_keys("D:\\test.mp4")
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1491, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/513/py_wombo/main.py", line 435, in <module>
    odysee_upload('888')
  File "D:/513/py_wombo/main.py", line 418, in odysee_upload
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="main-content"]/div/section[1]/div/div[2]/fieldset-section[2]/input-submit/button')).send_keys("D:\\513\\py_wombo\\mp4\\Party system supplying Tampa's.mp4")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

```
link:https://odysee.com/$/upload
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it has to be comman `,`, not `()` - `(By.XPATH,  '//*...')`, not `( By.XPATH('//*...') )`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself and found it was a selector problem

```
var = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']")
var.send_keys('D:\\test.mp4')
```